# Javascript prevent default not being executed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, preventdefault

I am new to javascript and I have been playing around with prevent default command for ajax pagination and I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/6pqfH/2/

```
$('.pagination').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // fade out current content
    $('.results').css("opacity", "0.5");
    // load new content
    // ....
    // unfade
    $('.results').css("opacity", "1");
    // go back up to top of the page
    $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working, it links to a new page instead of executing the fade in and out and bringing it back to the top of the page. I have checked the code for the opacity and scoll and it seems to be right so where am I going wrong here?

Comment: From my console: `SyntaxError: illegal character @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:27` (`#` isn't a JavaScript comment character.) Your console (`Ctrl+K` in FF, `Ctrl+J` in Chrome, `F12` in IE) should be your first stop for diagnosing errors.

Comment: @apsillers: typical programmers mistake dude, just replace them with `//` and proceed with your analysis

Comment: Thank you for the tip, it seemed to show it as a comment in jfiddle but I have learnt something now.

Comment: @Jimmy:is this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/6pqfH/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does both steps, The reason why you do not see it is that it does it right away. You need to add a delay or animation to break it up.

```
$('.pagination').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // fade out current content
    $('.results').css("opacity", "0.5");
    // load new content
    // ....
    // unfade
    $('.results').fadeTo('slow', 1, function() {
      $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's what I think you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/6pqfH/6/

```
<a class="pagination" id="num" href="#">4</a>
```

I replaced the hred="/test" by href="#" this way the a will take you to the top alone.